Solving 2D Rotational GPE and Finding Overlap Of Solutions
I want to generate those figures (fig 2) by solving equation no 7 from this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.06327 for different rotation values (\Omega) and calculate overlap(F(\Omega)) for plotting with \Omega.

boundary = 6; xl = yl = -boundary;  xr = 
 yr = boundary; finalt = 2; g = 100; 
seedwave[x_, 
  y_] := ((x + I*y)/Sqrt[\[Pi]]) Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/2] Exp[
   2 \[Pi] I RandomReal[]];

sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{-D[\[Psi][x, y, t], 
       t] == -0.5 Laplacian[\[Psi][x, y, t], {x, y}] + 
      0.5*(x^2 + y^2)*\[Psi][x, y, t] + 
      g *Abs[\[Psi][x, y, t]]^2*\[Psi][x, y, t] - 
      I *\[CapitalOmega]* (y*D[\[Psi][x, y, t], x] - 
         x*D[\[Psi][x, y, t], y]), \[Psi][x, y, 0] == seedwave[x, y],
    \[Psi][xl, y, t] == seedwave[xl, y],
    \[Psi][xr, y, t] == seedwave[xr, y],
    \[Psi][x, yl, t] == seedwave[x, yl],
    \[Psi][x, yr, t] == seedwave[x, yr]
    },
   \[Psi][x, y, t], {x, xl, xr}, {y, yl, yr}, {t, 0, 
    finalt}, {\[CapitalOmega]}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MinPoints" -> 40, "MaxPoints" -> 81, "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}},
    MaxSteps -> 10^6];


Table[DensityPlot[
  Evaluate[Abs[sol[\[CapitalOmega]][x, y, finalt]]], {x, xl, xr}, {y, 
   yl, yr}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 350, 
  LabelStyle -> {24, Bold, Large, Black}, 
  FrameLabel -> {{"y", None}, {"x", 
     Row[{Style["\[CapitalOmega]=", 
        FontSize -> 30], \[CapitalOmega]}]}}], {\[CapitalOmega], 0.1, 
  1, 0.1}]

EDIT
IF I add noise then its giving some vortices but result is very bad. This following program takes about 7-8mins with ParallelDo.If you reduce "i" in ParrallelDo loop it will take even lesser time.
    Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
Needs["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"];

boundary = 6; xl = yl = -boundary;  xr = yr = boundary;
 finalt = 2; g = 100; \[CapitalOmega] = Range[0.2, 0.95, 0.05];

nmax = 24;
pR = RandomFunction[
   OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess[0, 1., xr/nmax/Sqrt[2]], {0, 2 xr, 
    xr/nmax}];
xR = Interpolation[pR, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
etax[x_] := xR[x];

qR = RandomFunction[
   OrnsteinUhlenbeckProcess[0, 1., yr/nmax/Sqrt[2]], {0, 2 yr, 
    yr/nmax}];
yR = Interpolation[qR, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
etay[y_] := yR[y];

seedwave[x_, y_] := ((x + I*y)/Sqrt[Sqrt[\[Pi]]])*
   Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/2] Exp[2 \[Pi]  I  etax[x + 6] etay[y + 6]];
ParallelDo[
 sol[i] = 
   NDSolveValue[{-D[\[Psi][x, y, t], 
         t] == -0.5  Laplacian[\[Psi][x, y, t], {x, y}] + 
        0.5*(x^2 + y^2)*\[Psi][x, y, t] + 
        g *Abs[\[Psi][x, y, t]]^2*\[Psi][x, y, t] - 
        I *\[CapitalOmega][[i]]* (y*D[\[Psi][x, y, t], x] - 
           x*D[\[Psi][x, y, t], y]),
      \[Psi][x, y, 0] == seedwave[x, y],
      \[Psi][xl, y, t] == seedwave[xl, y],
      \[Psi][xr, y, t] == seedwave[xr, y],
      \[Psi][x, yl, t] == seedwave[x, yl],
      \[Psi][x, yr, t] == seedwave[x, yr]
      },
     \[Psi], {x, xl, xr}, {y, yl, yr}, {t, 0, finalt},
     Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
         "MinPoints" -> 40, "MaxPoints" -> 81, 
         "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}, MaxSteps -> 10^6] // Quiet;, {i, 1,
   16}]

Plot
ParallelTable[
 DensityPlot[Abs[sol[i][x, y, finalt]]^2, {x, xr, xl}, {y, yr, yl}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 200, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}], {i, 1, 16}]

Overlap
F\[CapitalOmega] = 
 ParallelTable[{i, 
   Abs[NIntegrate[
     Conjugate[sol[i][x, y, finalt]] sol[i + 1][x, y, finalt], {x, xr,
       xl}, {y, yr, yl}, PrecisionGoal -> 4, AccuracyGoal -> 5]]}, {i,
    1, 15}]

I am still not getting the proper vortices and the integral showing this massage "evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries"

In the paper they noted, that "The real-time propagation can successfully work only with a meaningful initial wave function", while you use analytical solution. :)

@AlexTrounev  I am trying to find the solution in imaginary-time propagation method. In the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.06327 on page 9, under fig.4 they have mentioned using the above used initial wave-function. But at the bottom of page 9 they also mentioned importance of random-phase modulation. My goal is to find the integral F for different \Omega after successfully getting the vortices. They also mentioned \Omega=0.4 is the cutoff after which vortices emerges.

@AlexTrounev They are defining initial \psi in this way. I think RANDNUM is doing the trick    DO j = 0, NY; DO i = 0, NX
K=(i+1)(j+1)  ;  \psi_int(i,j) =  EXP(-(-x^2(i)+y^2(j))/2) * (x(i)+Iy(j))* EXP(2PI I* RANDNUM(K))   END DO; END DO

In your solution, there are no vortices at all. And yes, they made the trick with initial data. ;) .

@AlexTrounev If you run the code in NDSolveValue for a particular \Omega say 0.8 it will give you a single vortex. But the number of vortices remain same irrespective of \Omega value.

@AlexTrounev I have tried to add noise in EDIT, it's giving some vortices.

Try to reproduce initial data from the code  DO j = 0, NY; DO i = 0, NX K=(i+1)*(j+1) ; \psi_int(i,j) = EXP(-(-x^2(i)+y^2(j))/2) * (x(i)+Iy(j)) EXP(2*PI* I* RANDNUM(K)) END DO; END DO

I guess the answer could be very long. First, we need to discuss the method you use. I tried to reproduce the initial state that they use in the program.
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

 boundary = 6; xl = yl = -boundary; xr = 
 yr = boundary; finalt = 2; g = 100; dt = 1/50; reg = 
 Rectangle[{xl, yl}, {xr, yr}]; mesh = 
 ToElementMesh[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> (12/256)^2]

 (*ElementMesh[{{-6., 6.}, {-6., 6.}}, {QuadElement[
   "<" 65536 ">"]}]*)

 points = mesh["Coordinates"]; dim = 
 Dimensions[points]; hx = (xr - xl)/Sqrt[dim[[1]]]; hy = (yr - yl)/
  Sqrt[dim[[1]]];
fp = Function[{x, 
     y}, ((x + I*y)/Sqrt[\[Pi]]) Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/2] Exp[
      2 \[Pi] I RandomReal[((x - xl)/hx + 1) ( (y - yl)/hy + 1)]]] @@@
    points;
seedwave = ListInterpolation[fp, mesh];

Visualization
DensityPlot[Abs[seedwave[x, y]], {x, xl, xr}, {y, yl, yr}, 
 ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> All]


It looks like foam. To get the system out of this state, it is necessary to use an explicit difference scheme with a very small step.
I don't believe that a quantum system can have such a state.
Therefore, I developed my own numerical method quantum vortex simulation described in several papers including this one Analytical Solutions for a Supersymmetric Wave-Equation for Quasiparticles in a Quantum System. The essence of this method is that the initial state should be taken as a state with several vortices. Then, in the process of evolution of the system, some of the vortices either disappear or new ones are added. I found an analytical solution that describes the multi-vortex state. Let's consider one of these solutions.
Em = {{1, -3.5810464606428707`}, {2, -4.65633094550589`}, {3, \
-5.5364983544147215`}, {4, -6.236219516197587`}, {5, \
-6.7668440323388745`}, {6, -7.137033466197102`}, {7, \
-7.353460458697432`}, {8, -7.421347432232933`}, {9, \
-7.3448512902358205`}, {10, -7.1273345545385505`}, {11, \
-6.771557737470864`}, {12, -6.279817707670113`}, {13, \
-5.654048788357715`}, {14, -4.895897806921574`}, {15, \
-4.006780661001332`}};
A1 = Table[{m, 
    First[FindMaximum[{Abs[
        1/x E^((I x^2)/Sqrt[2]) (x^2)^((1 + m)/2)
           LaguerreL[
           1/8 (-4 - I Sqrt[2] (Pi/2)^2 - 4 m + 
              2 I Sqrt[2] (m 1.4 + Em[[m, 2]])), m, -I Sqrt[2] x^2]], 
       x <= 3}, {x, 2.5}]]}, {m, 1, 15}];
fs1[t_, x_, p_] := 
 Sum[( E^((I x^2)/Sqrt[2]) (x^2)^((1 + m)/2)
     LaguerreL[
     1/8 (-4 - I Sqrt[2] (Pi/2)^2 - 4 m + 
        2 I Sqrt[2] (m 1.4 + Em[[m, 2]])), m, -I Sqrt[2] x^2])/x*
   Exp[I*m*p - I*t*Em[[m, 2]]]/A1[[m, 2]], {m, {1, 7, 15}}]
psi0[x_, y_] := fs1[0, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]]

This solution describes 7 vortices that are located on a disk of radius 3. Now we plug initial state in the evolution equation you use, and we get at $\Omega=1.6$ the following picture.

So, in the final state we see a central vortex and 6 vortices around, that is exactly what you were going to get. We used code based on linear FEM,
<< NDSolve`FEM`

psi[omega_] := 
 Module[{Lx = 3, Ly = 3, tmax = 1, 
   dt = 1/50, \[CapitalOmega] = omega, \[Beta] = 100},
  \[ScriptCapitalR] = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 9, {x, y}];
  \[CapitalPsi][0][x_, y_] := psi0[x, y];
  Do[\[CapitalPsi][t] = 
    NDSolveValue[{(\[Psi][x, y] - \[CapitalPsi][t - dt][x, y])/dt == 
       0.5  Laplacian[\[Psi][x, y], {x, y}] - 
        I \[CapitalOmega] (x*D[\[Psi][x, y], {y, 1}] - 
           y*D[\[Psi][x, y], {x, 
              1}]) - (\[Beta]  Abs[\[CapitalPsi][t - dt][x, y]]^2 + 
           0.5 ( x^2 + y^2))*\[Psi][x, y],
      DirichletCondition[\[Psi][x, y] == \[CapitalPsi][0][x, y], 
       True]}, \[Psi], {x, y} \[Element] \[ScriptCapitalR], 
     Method -> {"FiniteElement", InterpolationOrder -> {\[Psi] -> 2}, 
       "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.1}}], {t, dt, tmax, 
    dt}]; \[CapitalPsi][t]]

Example of usage
psi[2.4]; // AbsoluteTiming

It takes about 53s on my very slow Silver Pentium. Finally, we have central vortex and 14 vortices around.
Table[ContourPlot[
  Evaluate[
   Abs[\[CapitalPsi][t][x, y]]], {x, y} \[Element] \[ScriptCapitalR], 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t*1.}], PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 10, 
  ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  ContourStyle -> Green, Exclusions -> None], {t, 0, 1, 1/5}]


Perhaps this program will be useful for you.
Update 1. Code with normalization
Em = {{1, -3.5810464606428707`}, {2, -4.65633094550589`}, {3, \
-5.5364983544147215`}, {4, -6.236219516197587`}, {5, \
-6.7668440323388745`}, {6, -7.137033466197102`}, {7, \
-7.353460458697432`}, {8, -7.421347432232933`}, {9, \
-7.3448512902358205`}, {10, -7.1273345545385505`}, {11, \
-6.771557737470864`}, {12, -6.279817707670113`}, {13, \
-5.654048788357715`}, {14, -4.895897806921574`}, {15, \
-4.006780661001332`}};
A1 = Table[{m, 
    First[FindMaximum[{Abs[
        1/x E^((I x^2)/Sqrt[2]) (x^2)^((1 + m)/2)
           LaguerreL[
           1/8 (-4 - I Sqrt[2] (Pi/2)^2 - 4 m + 
              2 I Sqrt[2] (m 1.4 + Em[[m, 2]])), m, -I Sqrt[2] x^2]], 
       x <= 3}, {x, 2.5}]]}, {m, 1, 15}];
fs1[t_, x_, p_] := 
 Sum[( E^((I x^2)/Sqrt[2]) (x^2)^((1 + m)/2)
     LaguerreL[
     1/8 (-4 - I Sqrt[2] (Pi/2)^2 - 4 m + 
        2 I Sqrt[2] (m 1.4 + Em[[m, 2]])), m, -I Sqrt[2] x^2])/x*
   Exp[I*m*p - I*t*Em[[m, 2]]]/A1[[m, 2]], {m, {1, 7, 15}}]
psi0[x_, y_] := fs1[0, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y]];


<< NDSolve`FEM`

psi[omega_] := 
 Module[{Lx = 3, Ly = 3, tmax = 1, 
   dt = 1/50, \[CapitalOmega] = omega, \[Beta] = 100},
  \[ScriptCapitalR] = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 9, {x, y}]; 
  reg = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 9, {x, y}]; 
  mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1]; 
  nrm[0] = 
   NIntegrate[Abs[psi0[x, y]]^2, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
    AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 4];
  \[CapitalPsi][0][x_, y_] := psi0[x, y];
  Do[\[CapitalPsi][t] = 
    NDSolveValue[{(\[Psi][x, y] - \[CapitalPsi][t - dt][x, y]/
           Sqrt[nrm[t - dt]])/dt == 
       0.5 Laplacian[\[Psi][x, y], {x, y}] - 
        I \[CapitalOmega] (x*D[\[Psi][x, y], {y, 1}] - 
           y*D[\[Psi][x, y], {x, 
              1}]) - (\[Beta] Abs[\[CapitalPsi][t - dt][x, y]]^2 + 
           0.5 ( x^2 + y^2))*\[Psi][x, y],
      DirichletCondition[\[Psi][x, y] == \[CapitalPsi][0][x, y], 
       True]}, \[Psi], {x, y} \[Element] \[ScriptCapitalR], 
     Method -> {"FiniteElement", InterpolationOrder -> {\[Psi] -> 2}, 
       "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.1}}]; 
   nrm[t] = 
    NIntegrate[Abs[\[CapitalPsi][t][x, y]]^2, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
     AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 4];, {t, dt, tmax, 
    dt}]; \[CapitalPsi][t]]


psi[1.6]; // AbsoluteTiming

It takes about 66s. Visualization
Table[ContourPlot[
  Evaluate[Abs[\[CapitalPsi][t][x, y]]]/
   Sqrt[nrm[t]], {x, y} \[Element] \[ScriptCapitalR], 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"t = ", t*1.}], PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 10, 
  ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  ContourStyle -> Green, Exclusions -> None], {t, 0, 1, 1/5}]


Update 2. To compute energy levels let consider 3D analytical solution described torus vortex - see Figure 6 in our paper
f[x_, z_, m_, k_, \[CapitalOmega]_, E0_, p_] := ( 
   E^((I x^2)/Sqrt[2]) (x^2)^((1 + m)/2)
     LaguerreL[
     1/8 (-4 - I Sqrt[2] k^2 - 4 m + 
        2 I Sqrt[2]  (m  \[CapitalOmega] + E0)), m, -I Sqrt[2] x^2])/x*Cos[Pi*z/2]*Exp[I*m*p];

From this general solution we construct 2D solution on a disk of radius $x\le 3$ at $\Omega =1.4$ as follows
psi=If[x<=3,f[x, 0, m, Pi/2, 1.4, E0, 0],0]

Therefore we have for E0 equation
en = {-3.65, -4.7, -5.6, -6.23, -6.9, -6.99, -7.37, -7.37, \
-7.37, -6.9, -6.76, -6.49, -6, -5, -5};

 Em = 
 Table[{m, 
   E0 /. Quiet@
     FindRoot[
      Abs[f[3, 0, m, Pi/2, 1.4, E0, 0]] == 0, {E0, en[[m]]}]}, {m, 1, 
   15, 1}]

(*Out[]= {{1, -3.58105}, {2, -4.65633}, {3, -5.5365}, {4, -6.23622}, \
{5, -6.76684}, {6, -7.13703}, {7, -7.35346}, {8, -7.42135}, {9, \
-7.34485}, {10, -7.12733}, {11, -6.77156}, {12, -6.27982}, {13, \
-5.65405}, {14, -4.8959}, {15, -4.00678}}*)

Although this solution seems limited and is valid only for a given value of omega, it can nevertheless be used as an initial data for any value of omega. Because in the process of evolution energy takes on the value that corresponds to the current state.

Many Many thanks @AlexTrounev. I have couple of questions:[1 How you calculated Em, by using Eq.15 from your paper?[2].I am little bit confused about use of \psi and \Psi in NDSolveValue.In interaction \Psi is used but for other terms \psi is used. [3] If I integrate the density it should give particle no(1000) in this case or 1 if it's normalized.But I am getting different value.[4]There is a cutoff value for \Omega(0.4 for this case) after which vortices start to appear. But I am getting at least 1 vortice for even \Omega=0.01.

1.Don't pay attention to this question. Take the function fs1 as it is. 2. This is called an implicit linear step. $\psi$ computed at $t+dt$, wile $\Psi[t]$ taken from previous step.  3. Function $\Psi$ not normalized same as in your code. But you can add normalization at each step.  4. I'm not sure that the criteria you give $\Omega = 0.4$ are really fair.  For example, I see one central vortex at $\Omega =0.8$, while in the paper sited, they computed 7 vortices from foam state. ;)

Thanks for the clearifications @AlexTrounev.Do you think the foam state can give the vortices in Crank Nicloson Method as the paper shows in mathematica? Can you please add the normalization condition and repost it without Em?

@ArghaDebnath See update 1 with normalization line. Results are less contrast compared to nonnormalized case above. I try to make something with foam on the grid $256\times 256$, but it takes all memory on my laptop. Now I try to compile code and solve it with "C". But memory problem still persists. Please note, that in the paper they compute with using supercomputer. Whereas my method doesn't require anything special. Only knowledge about quantum states is needed. :)

Thanks, @AlexTrounev. Can you please clearify origin of Em in your program?

@ArghaDebnath See Update 2.

Thanks, @AlexTrounev.
